# how to express `\1` literally in R regular expression?

Tags: regex, r

```
grep(pattern="\\","\\1")
Error in grep(pattern = "\\", "\\1") : 
invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'
```

How to express  `\1` literally? can `\\1`  not express `\1` literally in R regular expression?

Comment: Try `\\\\` for `\` and `\\\\1` for `\1`.

Comment: As I stated in your previous question, you must escape the backslash itself. So ``\\`` matches one backslash, ``\\\\`` matches two backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\\1` seems to represent `\1`, the first `\` escapes the second so it sees it as a string and not a command.

```
cat file
test 1
test \1 more
test \\1 more
1 test
```

```
grep '\\1' file
test \1 more
test \\1 more
```

```
awk '/\\1/' file
test \1 more
test \\1 more
```